# Return string variable in map without cloning

Tags: rust

I'm writing a simple fizzbuzz in Rust:

```
fn main() {
    let fizz = "Fizz".to_string() ;
    let buzz = "Buzz".to_string() ;
    let fizzbuzz = "FizzBuzz".to_string() ;

    let even_numbers = (1..16)
        .into_iter()
        .map( |n|
            if n % 15 == 0 { fizzbuzz.to_owned() }
                else if n % 3 == 0 { fizz.to_owned() }
                else if n % 5 == 0 { buzz.to_owned() }
                else { n.to_string() }
        ).collect::<Vec<String>>() ;

    dbg!(even_numbers) ;
}
```

I'm insisted to use `map()` instead of for loops and printing line by line.

But this doesn't seem right, because `.to_owned()` makes a cloned copy of the String. So I want to do this instead:

```
if n % 15 == 0 { fizzbuzz }
    else if n % 3 == 0 { fizz }
    else if n % 5 == 0 { buzz }
    else { n.to_string() }
```

So this will return whatever the variables have. Also keep of fizz, buzz and fizzbuzz variables into memory as long as the `even_numbers` vector is in memory.

How can I achieve that in rust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33419930/7076153) application:

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn main() {
    let fizz = "Fizz";
    let buzz = "Buzz";
    let fizzbuzz = "FizzBuzz";

    let even_numbers = (1..16)
        .into_iter()
        .map(|n| {
            if n % 15 == 0 {
                fizzbuzz.into()
            } else if n % 3 == 0 {
                fizz.into()
            } else if n % 5 == 0 {
                buzz.into()
            } else {
                n.to_string().into()
            }
        })
        .collect::<Vec<Cow<_>>>();

    dbg!(even_numbers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of `Vec` depends on what you need to do with this collection further. If read-only access is enough you may use `std::rc::Rc` reference counting pointer. Then the string data is not cloned but reference counter is incremented instead.

Also as Stargateur mentioned in the comment below you can keep `str` instead of `String` which is more effective.

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let fizz: Rc<str> = Rc::from("Fizz");
    let buzz: Rc<str> = Rc::from("Buzz");
    let fizzbuzz: Rc<str> = Rc::from("FizzBuzz");

    let even_numbers = (1..16)
        .into_iter()
        .map(|n| {
            if n % 15 == 0 {
                fizzbuzz.clone()
            } else if n % 3 == 0 {
                fizz.clone()
            } else if n % 5 == 0 {
                buzz.clone()
            } else {
                n.to_string().into()
            }
        })
        .collect::<Vec<Rc<str>>>();

    dbg!(even_numbers);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=11e3227190f22fd6d732deb18f39dc30)

Comment: I would not advice use this, this would make an double allocation. It's highly ineffective in this situation.

Comment: should be better https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=11e3227190f22fd6d732deb18f39dc30

Comment: I agree that this version should be more effective if read-only string is needed. Thanks!